# Atualizar tela aplicativo react native quando dados da api mudam

Tags: react-native

Olá,
Se alguém puder me ajudar eu agradeço eu preciso fazer a aplicação atualizar automaticamente quando os dados do backend são atualizados, nessa parte do código se eu salvar o código ele recarrega a tela com as notas informações, do contrario ela não atualiza sozinha, existe alguma forma de fazer o reload da aplicação sempre que os dados da Api mudam, abaixo o código.

```
import  React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View, Image, Dimensions,Text } from 'react-native'
import Autor from '../autorComunicado'
import {api} from '../../services/api'

export default function ListaMensagens() {
    
    const [mensagens, setMensagens] = useState([])

    useEffect(()=>{

        api.get('/mensagem3').then(response=>{
            setMensagens(response.data)
        }).catch(error=>{
            console.error(error)
        })

    },[])
            const anexo = 'teste'
    return(

        <>
            {mensagens.map((item, index)=>{
               return(
                <View style={styles.container} key={index}>
                    <Autor nickname={item.id} mensagem={item.mensagem} data={item.data_envio}/>
                    <Image source={{uri:'http://xxx.xxx.xxx/files/'+item.anexo}}  style={styles.image}/>
                </View>
               )
    
            })}

        </>

    )
    
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container:{
        flex: 1,

    },
    image:{
        width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
        height: Dimensions.get('window').width * 3/4,
        resizeMode: 'contain',
    },
})
```

Answer (score -3):

Amigo,

Para fazer isso você vai precisar usar uma comunicação via Socket. Configure o SocketIO no servidor Back-End, para ele enviar uma notificação após a gravação dos dados da API, esta mensagem deve ser redirecionada para o Aplicativo mobile deve estar conectado no Socket para ficar aguardando o recebimento uma notificação indicando que houve uma atualização, você pode se conectar ao Socket através do useEffect().

Espero ter ajudado.